# What exists between tolerant and enthusiastic?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

The use of tolerance comes with varying degrees of indifference to something, with often unstated or deliberately understated degrees of disapproval for that thing. For example, *"While I'm tolerant of those that eat meat, I don't personally do it."*

Enthusiasm, on the other hand, conveys endorsement. *"I'm excited that people are eating meat, though I don't personally don't do it."*

*Ambivalence* immediately comes to mind, but that negates any inclination toward the subject, be it positive or negative.

What word indicates *"I think that's fine, but it isn't for me"*, without the sort of negative connotation that *tolerance* lends, yet lacks implied or enthusiastic endorsement? What word exists between tolerance and enthusiasm for something?

Comment: What about tolerate?

Comment: @SrJoven 'tolerate' carries the same connotation for me. It implies a sense of disapproval.

Comment: I'm okay with that.

Comment: I think "grading" terms like this is a bit of a mug's game, but you might like to note that given usages such as *"My client would be happy to proceed on that basis"* and *"I'll be happy to spend the rest of my life with you"*, ***happy*** can easily stretch across both OP's "extremes".

Comment: It's nice that you're having a discussion about my question within earshot, yet excluding me. Would someone kindly tell me what POB means?

Comment: POB stands for Primarily Opinion Based, @TimPost - one of the options to close a question.  I think that your request has merit since it might bring out a number of interesting choices running the gamut between "tolerance" and "enthusiasm".

Comment: @KristinaLopez I think that my question is rather narrowly-scoped, or at least I thought it was :) If the trepidation stems from worry that this will attract too many answers, I honestly don't see how. I was pretty specific.

Comment: 'Endorsement' doesn't demand 'enthusiasm': it is sometimes preceded by 'grudging'. 'Endorsive' is given by RHKWebster's.

Comment: May I recommend consulting a thesaurus?

Comment: As a vegan I "frown upon." But I'm going to put up with it and not do anything about it. I did include this in my answer.

Comment: You're shooting for something less than that...  anyway two answers posted. One with lots of words and one yelling at your word choice choice. Hopefully one or both is useful.

Comment: @keshlam, how would a thesaurus aid in finding a term that's not equivalent in meaning to two others, but midway between them in degree?

Comment: Thesauri list near-synonyms, which could include the term being sought. Recursing -- looking up the matches found in the thesaurus -- often finds additional near-matches which may get you a step closer to what you're looking for. I've found this a useful approach when wordsmithing. I grant that it may not work as well for non-native-speakers, but it's a tool worth learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps *accepting*.  *American Heritage* offers these two definitions (among others) for *[accept](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/accept)*

> To regard as proper, usual, or right: *Such customs are widely accepted*.
>
> To endure resignedly or patiently: *accept one's fate*.

Comment: To directly insert this into his sentence, *I accept that people are eating meat* sounds more like the second definition than the first to me. Something like *I'm accepting of people who eat meat* sounds more like what he's going for (to my ears).

Comment: @TimS.I think there is a subtle difference between *I accept that [but resent] ...* and *I am accepting that [and am okay with it] ...*

Answer (score 4):

The term ***agnostic*** is often used to express such a sentiment. When applied to a non-religious context, it means someone who is uncommitted one way or another on a position.

> Regarding whether or not to eat meat, I am *agnostic*.

Along the same lines is ***impartial***, which means to treat all sides equally.

> I am *impartial* to vegetarians, although I am not one myself.

Heavily related is the term ***open-minded***, which denotes an unbiased willingness to consider new ideas.

> I am *open-minded* toward meat-eaters, but not toward meat packing plants.

Comment: Note that the issue on which the person is undecided has to be the truth/falsity of some proposition. So that example only "works" to the extent the reader understands you to be talking about the issue of whether "one should [or ethically can] eat meat". If the speaker was instead talking about their own eating, it would be either a misuse of 'agnostic' in place of 'undecided' (e.g. "I haven't decided whether to go vegetarian") or a rather unusual way of speaking about something the truth of which they controlled (e.g. "I take no position on whether I'm about to pick a vegetarian entree").

Comment: @TerryN: That is taking the religious interpretation and reapplying it to the non-religious context, which is not appropriate. For non-religious issues, agnostic can be used to mean neither for nor against. In business contexts, it can be used to mean a product interoperates with competing vendors equally well.

Answer (score 3):

If I don't have an objection to something, I'd say:

> I'm *okay* with that.
>
> That's *fine*.
>
> It's *acceptable*.

Comment: Along these lines I would add `comfortable`. "I'm comfortable with people eating meat."

Answer (score 3):

In order:

- Prohibiting, disallowing, vetoing
- Objecting
- Condemn
- Dismissive
- Frown upon
- Unpreferred
- **Tolerant**
- Unbothered
- Ambivalent (also see thesaurus for synonyms)
- Considering
- Accepting (acceptable is likely the more natural use)
- Condoning (different flavor: active acceptance but possible disapproval)
- Preferring
- Wanting (and synonyms)
- Agreeing
- Approving
- Supportive
- Adamant, unwavering, determined
- **Enthusiastic**
- Ecstatic

"Out of bounds" adjectives may be inverted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it is possible to be fully neutral without dropping your perspective from it. As soon as you introduce yourself, you are automatically assuming a perspective against which a following statement will be compared, so absolute neutrality becomes improbable. Consider the difference between:

> 1. Some people like the color blue.
> 2. I tolerate that some people like the color blue.
> 3. I value that some people like the color blue.

That said, I think you could use *acknowledge* (or *recognize* or *understand*) in this context to express a relatively neutral opinion.

> I *acknowledge* that some people like the color blue.

It expresses that you are not ignorant of the existence of something and at the same time implies no value judgement apart from that you (probably) like a different color.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that that **tolerant** and **tolerating** have somewhat opposite connotations. Do you actively have to put up with something, or by nature aren't bothered by it?

I suspect you won't be able to find a perfect word (although I tried in my other answer). Do you know anyone who doesn't drink but doesn't find anything particularly wrong with it? I can replay a few of those conversations in my head from memory, and the tee-totaler *never* finds a way to describe it. In a minor argument, at some point you need a reason *not* to do something, and unless you have one that applies to yourself and not to others, this is rough.

But, [I don't know](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-greenhouse-hamburger/), it wouldn't hurt to just admit to interested parties that you do in fact find something objectionable about eating meat. In other words, the problem might be content more than verbiage, given that you have a stance that led to you taking an action and you can't find a word to explain why you're taking the action but not for any particular stance.

It's somewhat a cultural issue also. Since people generally want you to do what they're doing (pretty sure this is cross-cultural), humankind hasn't necessarily evolved a great word for "no judgment but I'm exempting myself." Because no one would accept that, we'd just push and argue against it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might look at synomyms for *indifferent*

- dispassionate
- unprejudiced
- nonpartisan
- impartial
- detached
- equitable
- neutral

In particular *indifferent* and the first five alternatives have a prefix indicating the *lack of feelings* (either way) for whatever noun the adjective is being applied to.

Answer (score 1):

The following words come to mind:

*Acceptable:* just good enough, but not very good

*All right:*  satisfactory or reasonably good

*Convenient:*  suitable for the purposes and needs and causing the least difficulty

Answer (score 1):

How about a state of merely being *content*?  It seems as if you're looking for something that implies approval, but rather luke-warm approval.

*I'm content for others to eat meat.*